# Как заполнить в symfony 6 данные для swagger(OpenApi)?

Tags: symfony, swagger

мне надо заполнит документацию для swagger.
Похоже на [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64208289/how-to-add-json-request-and-response-examples-in-swagger-openapi)

```
 @OA\Parameter(
  name="body",
  in="path",
  required=true,
  @OA\JsonContent(
     type="object",
     @OA\Property(property="property1", type="number"),
     @OA\Property(property="property2", type="number"),
  ),
```

)

```
  @OA\Response(
  response=200,
  description="",
  @OA\JsonContent(
     type="object",
     @OA\Property(property="property1", type="number"),
     @OA\Property(property="property2", type="number"),
  )
```

)

но для symfony 6 в таком стиле

```
  #[OA\Response(
    response: 200,
    description: 'Register user'
)]
#[OA\Parameter(
    name: 'body',
    in: 'path',
    required: true,
    new OA\JsonContent(
        type: "object",
        new OA\Property(property: "test", type: "string", example: "email@eamil.ru")
    )
)]
```

как правильно писать? сейчас у меня где new OA\JsonContent подчеркивается красным

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего так

```
#[OA\Response(
    response: 200,
    description: 'Register user'
)]
#[OA\Parameter(
    name: 'body',
    in: 'path',
    required: true
)]
#[OA\JsonContent(type: "object")]
#[OA\Property(property: "test", type: "string", example: "email@eamil.ru")]
```

Comment: так тоже не сработал

Answer (score 0):

Как то так у меня получилось решать

```
#[Route('/register', name: 'register', methods: ['POST'])]
#[OA\Response(
    response: 200,
    description: 'Register user'
)]
#[OA\RequestBody(
    content: new OA\JsonContent(type: "object",
        example:'{
          "email": "newuser5@test.com",
          "password": "Test1234"
        }'
    )
)]
```